# MVC music store variation - "Sequence contains no elements" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I wanted to create my own basic online shop so I had a look around and in the end chose to modify the MVC Music Store tutorial in to something tailored to my needs.

I am still in the early stages and so far, my version is very similar to the tutorial version with the exception of the tables and associated classes.  Where the tutorial has Genres, Albums and Artists - I have a more simple Product and Category and I have adapted my project accordingly but I am getting an error.

It only happens in the StoreController\Browse section.  When I try and view all items in a specific category, I get a System.InvalidOperationException "Sequence contains no elements"

The code used in the controller is:

```
public ActionResult Browse(string cat)
{
var categoryModel = storeDB.Categories.Include("Products")
    .Single(g => g.CatName == cat);

return View(categoryModel);
}
```

And the view looks like this:

```
@model TPATK_shop.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
}

<h2>Browsing Category: @Model.CatName</h2>

<ul>
    @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
    {
        <li>
            @product.ProdName
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

I have all of my classes and entity set up as follows:

```
namespace TPATK_shop.Models
{
    public partial class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CatName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace TPATK_shop.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string ProdName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }

        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace TPATK_shop.Models
{
    public class TPATKStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have been researching the issue and I cant seem to find a solution. I have tried singleordefault but I still get the error.

I have confirmed that all the data is present in the DB and the keys are correct.

When my project fires up, an entry in the global.asax fires the following code to populate the DB (for test purposes - as detailed in the walkthrough)

```
namespace TPATK_shop.Models
{
    public class SampleData :  DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TPATKStoreEntities>
    //public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TPATKStoreEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(TPATKStoreEntities context)
        {
            var categories = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category { CatName = "50's" , Description = "50's stuff" },
                new Category { CatName = "Weddings" , Description = "Wedding stuff" },
                new Category { CatName = "Dribble Bibs" , Description = "Dribble bibs for kids" },
                new Category { CatName = "Xmas" , Description = "Xmas stuff" },
            };

            new List<Product>
            {
                new Product { ProdName = "Headband 1", Description = "Des for headband 1", Category = categories.Single(g => g.CatName == "50's"), Price = 8.99M, ImageURL = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
                new Product { ProdName = "Headband 2", Description = "Des for headband 2", Category = categories.Single(g => g.CatName == "Weddings"), Price = 8.99M, ImageURL = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
                new Product { ProdName = "Headband 3", Description = "Des for headband 3", Category = categories.Single(g => g.CatName == "Dribble Bibs"), Price = 8.99M, ImageURL = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
                new Product { ProdName = "Headband 4", Description = "Des for headband 4", Category = categories.Single(g => g.CatName == "Xmas"), Price = 8.99M, ImageURL = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
                new Product { ProdName = "Headband 4", Description = "Des for headband 5", Category = categories.Single(g => g.CatName == "Xmas"), Price = 8.99M, ImageURL = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
            }.ForEach(a => context.Products.Add(a));
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see why I am getting the error?  Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: delete your foreach code from the View for a moment and check what does `@Model.CatName` and `@Model.Products.Count()` show

Comment: Pankej - I have done what you suggested and I still get an error.  It breaks before it even gets to the view.

Comment: what error are you getting now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the supplied `cat` has not matching record in the database. Use `SingleOrDefault` method to retrieve the entity, it will return `null` if there wasn't a record.

```
public ActionResult Browse(string cat)
{
    var categoryModel = storeDB.Catagories.Include("Products")
        .SingleOrDefault(g => g.CatName == cat);

    if (categoryModel == null)
       return RedirectToAction("Index");

    return View(categoryModel);
}
```

It maybe the case that MVC can not bind a value to the `cat` parameter and is set to null. So check whether you are passing a query string argument named `cat`.

Comment: Hi Erange - I have done whan you said an the var categoryModel does come back as null.  When I debug, the storeDB does have data in it so it looks like it's not passing data to the categoryModel.  What can I do to see why this is happening?

Comment: @JimboJames Did you check whether the `cat` parameter has the correct value?

Comment: the value cat is null, I think you have identified the issue.  How can I correct this?  The value is in the url that come from the link.

Comment: Actually I sorted it - I had compltley forgotten that the parameter name must match the the one in the URL variable.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a spelling mistake which is causing the error. Instead of "Category", you have used "Catagory". Now since you have used POCO Code-first, there is a convention which pluralizes the Model name to match with database table. Since there is no such word as "CATAGORY", the plurization fails.

To make this error correct, either rename Catagory to Category everywhere and Change Catagories to Categories in DbContext class.

Or

you can decorate your Catagory class like following

```
[Table("Catagories"]
public class Catagory
```

if you follow this approach, change the spelling in Product Model from CategoryId to CatagoryId

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have made the changes and I am still getting the error.  I will repost the new code in the main question to see I have have understood you correctly.

Comment: You need to understand the conventions. Try the second option, its much easier. First one will require you to make changes at all the places

Comment: Just make sure that if you use Catagory, then use it at every place and decorate the Catagory model class with table attribute "Catagories". **OR** If you change Categary to Category, then make sure it's changed everywhere, along with change for Catagories to Categories..... You don't need to open another question. This is the only problem

Comment: I changed everything in all places.  There are no catagory or catagories in my project only category and categories.  See my revised code above to see if I have done this correctly and understood you.  Thank you for helping me with this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting the exception because using the Single method means that you expect there to be a Category returned, and if there isn't, it's an exceptional case.

In this situation that might be happening because your seeding code also seems to be missing an explicit addition of each Category to the context.

There also might be a problem because the EF Code First system tries to match keys based on property names. You have a Product referencing a *Catagory* object but uses a *CategoryID* identifier (with and "e", not an "a").

Comment: Regards the spelling mistake, I think that is fixed now.  As for the seeding error - how can I correct this?

Comment: You could just add a similar ForEach statement like you did for the Products list to add each Category to the context, like .ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c)). I see you've already found the problem now though, so this won't help :-) However, it might avoid you being surprised in future.